# Creating screenshots of iOS devices from OSX without Xcode

Tags: ios

Is there a way to create screenshots of iOS devices from OSX without using Xcode? I am looking for a fast way to do that.

I know 2 methods:

1. Using Xcode
2. Taking a screenshot on the device and sharing it using message/mail whatever

but both these methods are cumbersome and slow. I want to be able to create those screenhots fast.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't consider the standard method (#2) to be slow per se, so I wonder a bit which problem you are trying to solve here. Why do these screenshots need to be fast? Someone may find better ways here if you share some context.

Comment: You won't get much faster than method #2 (home + power button takes < 1 sec.), so I'm with Patrix on this one. What needs to be fast about your process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way that i've found is just using the iOS Simulator and then <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, which takes screenshots really quickly.

If you don't want to open Xcode to open the iOS Simulator, here's a useful answer telling you how to open the iOS Simulator directly or create a shortcut (or even from Terminal): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379622/how-to-run-iphone-emulator-without-starting-xcode

Answer (score 3):

You could use airplay mirroring to an Apple TV or your [Mac](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/) and take screenshots from those output displays

Edit: Also, just enable photo stream on iPhoto and your phone and it'll automatically upload any screenshots you take with the power and home buttons. I can't think of a faster method than that